# Error opening Laravel project after 30 minutes

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am getting errors when reloading the previously opened tab of my Laravel Project on my browser. There is no error on the page, I mean it loads correctly when I opened it half hour ago.

[image: It shows this error.]

The error says "**Trying to get property of non-object**"

```
4/4 ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object 
(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\resources\views\partials\mainheader.blade.php)
(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\resources\views\partials\mainheader.blade.php)
(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\resources\views\partials\mainheader.blade.php)
```

***ADDED: Only suspicious code that might be causing problem on `mainheader.blade.php` is, I am using `{{ Auth::user()->name }}`. But I am still confuse how I can Redirect this exception.***
What I thought was, it was due to error in `session` and `token expiration`, so I added this code to `app/Exception/handler.php`

```
if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {            
    return redirect('error/403')->withErrors(['token_error' => 'Sorry, your session seems to have expired. Please try again.']);
}
```

But, that was not solved. Could you please so me the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found my mistake.** Actually it was on the route, I should have added middleware for Auth.

```
Route::get('/home', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    return view('home');
}]);
```

Now, that's good and working.